# .NET naming conventions for solution with .NET Standard, .NET Core and .NET Framwork Projects

Tags: .net, .net-core, naming, .net-standard

I have found nothing on the web about the accepted naming conventions for a .NET solution which contains .NET Standard, .NET Core and .NET Framework projects.

In my case we had the following convention in our .NET Framwork project:

```
[CompanyName].[TechnologyName].[Feature]
```

Now we want to port this to .NET Standard and .NET Core. Not all of the classes inside the feature work on all of them, so we have a .NET Standard project which is referenced by the .NET Core project. The .NET Core project is then reference by the .NET Framework project. How should we now name our projects.

One solution would be to include the name of Standard or Core in the namespace:

```
[CompanyName].Standard.[TechnologyName].[Feature]
[CompanyName].Core.[TechnologyName].[Feature]
[CompanyName].[TechnologyName].[Feature]
```

or

```
[CompanyName].[TechnologyName].[Feature].Standard
[CompanyName].[TechnologyName].[Feature].Core
[CompanyName].[TechnologyName].[Feature]
```

But we want to know if there is a global naming convention for this.

Comment: I am not so convinced you need technology name as a part of naming your projects. Why is the type of underlying framework relevant for your project's naming? Name your stuffs according to what it does *for you*, from your perspective. May be a project running on .NET Core is cross-platform for you, in which case names would be like `[CompanyName].[Product].[Windows].[Feature]`, `[CompanyName].[Product].[Cross-Platform].[Feature]` etc.

Comment: @nawfal: One reason can be to distinguish several variants of a project that target different underlying frameworks.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think that would be an extremely rare scenario, consider how much code duplication that will lead do to. In any case that situation is when naming something like `[CompanyName].[Product].[Framework].[Feature]` or `[CompanyName].[Product].[Feature].[Framework]` would make sense because it is so from the perspective of your product. Just stick to one of those conventions. Anyway OP's case is different.

Comment: @nawfal: Actually, I think it is an extremely common scenario. A different target requires different dependency versions, hence one project file per target framework is often the way to go. No code is duplicated as the same files are included in all projects.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper makes sense. Hardly came across a situation though. I think over time such framework constraints are getting ridden more and more. I see your point anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the original guideline still stands. Take the sample `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. That is company, product and whatever below. .NET Standard or .NET Core version should be shipped under the same name just packaged for their target framework moniker. Take the sample of `Newtonsoft.Json`. If the API surface/feature set changes, go for a breaking version change or change the product name.

Don't get confused by the Core additions at Microsoft product names. They choose to make ASP.NET Core, .NET Core and EF Core new products to avoid misleading assumptions of a higher product version: ASP.NET 5.

Listening the ASP.NET community standup I can tell you that this topic came up and they concluded that not everything should be added a Core naming part.